# Find lowest value in a row and switch to column name?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I cant figure out a way to do this, Ex:

```
a       b       c       d       e

        p1      p2     p3   
a       132     354    475     p1

b       654     355    476     p2

c       789     356    477     p2
```

What is the formula to get the column e to give me the lowest value and instead of giving me the amount I want to get the column name (p1,p2 or p3)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INDEX`, `MATCH` and `MIN`. The formula for cell E2 would be:
`=INDEX(B1:D1,1,MATCH(MIN(B2:D2),B2:D2,0))`.

`MATCH` gets the column of the minimum, which is then used by `INDEX` to lookup the respective value in row 1 of its data range (your column headers).